# how to suspend users after 36hrs of inactive

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a script which will suspend users after 36hrs of no activity.

The code below is what i came up with. I know it may not work, but I'm stuck. I need help. I am using PHP and MYSQL.

```
$n = "SELECT * FROM tb_ph WHERE username ='$user'
                                    AND status ='sukses' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$regi = mysql_query($n);
$regr = mysql_fetch_array($regi);
$verify = time($regr["verify"]);
$username = $regr["username"];

$check = $verify + 1;
$now = time();
if($check < $now){
     mysql_query("UPDATE tb_users SET suspend='1' WHERE username='$username'");
 }
```

Comment: Where do you store time of last activity? Is it stored in the database?

Comment: it is stored in database. I have a table that stores transaction, what i want is users should be suspended if they don't start new transaction after 36 hours of previous successful transaction.

Answer (score 0):

if it is what i understand users being inactive you have to use javascript if only it is being inactive to catch events try this if no action the fire ajax to suspend the user, you cant use php for this cause it just runs when the page loads you can use a javascript event system.
          BROKEN DOWN:   I created var time and stored newdate and gettime. then i put a bind key if there is no activity meaning if the have not done anything like move mouse pressed a key, you can search more events, then  fire an ajax to delete them so probably you use cookies or probably sessions  to know which user to delete. Please if it works upvote it

```
       <script>
     var time = new Date().getTime();
     $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
         time = new Date().getTime();
     });

     function refresh() {
         if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 129600) 

      //delete user with ajax
            $.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
url: "//your url", 
data: {id: id}, //maybe from cookie or session 
cache: false, 
success: function(r){
//callback if you wish

}
});


     else 
             setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a table that stores transaction, what i want is users should be suspended if they don't start new transaction after 36 hours of previous successful transaction.

Comment: so it is like you are building something like MMM or transaction website i am a Nigerian also @faloyesogo you might need a cron job for that ever heard of it before it is very simple especially if you are using cpanel try using a google search php can never work for it i thought you meant inactivity when they are still online try running a google search on cron job and give me a feed back

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use here:

1) Use a cronjob that checks the database every hour (or every 10 minutes..you can even do every minute if you don't mind the overhead) for the last time. You only need to check the accounts that are still have the active flag set to 1. If the times are greater than 36 hours set the active flag to 0.

2) Depending on your app, you might not even want to worry about an active flag. Instead, when your user next tries to login you can just check to see when the last time they were active was. If it is greater than 36 hours ago, then just deny them access. In this scenario you do not need an active flag in your database because the timestamp fulfills the purpose for you.